# Web.config : showing detailed error information from subdirectory

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have an asp.net  web application .I have a  web.config in the root which will take care about the application related settings. as per my web.config,the site will not show any error messages to the end user,instead it will show a friendly error page. I have few sub direcorties in the root .Can i show error information in screen for files belongs to that sub directory by putting another web.config in the subdirectory ? What should be the values in web.config ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can add another web.config to your subfolder containing:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```